# simple objects and methods

Tags: java, object

Program is to add and average and list amount of times the "addNumber" method is called.

I can make the Amount work, but nothing else

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberStatistics stats = new NumberStatistics();
        stats.addNumber(3);
        stats.addNumber(5);
        stats.addNumber(1);
        stats.addNumber(2);
        System.out.println("Amount: " + stats.amountOfNumbers());
        System.out.println("sum: " + stats.sum());
        System.out.println("average: " + stats.average());
    }

public class NumberStatistics {
    private int amountOfNumbers;
    private int addNumber; 
    private double average; 
    private int sum; 

public NumberStatistics() {
    this.amountOfNumbers=amountOfNumbers; 
    this.average=0; 
    this.sum=0;
}

public void addNumber(int number) {
    number=addNumber; 
    addNumber++; 
    // code here
}
public int amountOfNumbers() {
    return addNumber; 
    // code , here
}
public int sum() {
    return this.addNumber++; 
}

public double average() {
    return sum() / addNumber; 
}
```

My incorrect output:

Amount: 4
sum: 4
average: 0.0

Comment: int/int always int in java

Comment: Integer division! @FastSnail answer should explain that to you. But look it up and read about it

Comment: Usually a sum is when you add all the numbers together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok lets start with the constructor.

```
public NumberStatistics() {
this.amountOfNumbers=amountOfNumbers; 
this.average=0; 
this.sum=0;}
```

Here when you create an object you initialize average and sum to 0 but
this.amountOfNumbers=amountOfNumbers; has no particular effect.
To sum up what i think you wanted to do is something like this:

```
public NumberStatistics()
{
   this.average = 0;//this keyword here is not needed but i used it since you did too
   this.sum = 0;
   this.amountOfNumbers = 0;
}
```

Then we go to this block of code here:

```
public void addNumber(int number) {
  number=addNumber; 
  addNumber++; 
}
```

Ok, this line makes no sense since you are setting the parameter equal to the addNumber variable which is something that does not help you at all, what i think you wanted to do here is the following:

```
public void addNumber(int number) {
   sum += number;//same as sum = sum + number; 
   amountOfNumbers++;//same as amountOfNumbers = amountOfNumbers +1;
}
```

Then you need a method that returns the average like this:

```
public double average() {
  return  average = sum / amountOfNumbers; //i use the average variable only because you did, 
  //the most efficient way here is just to return sum / amountOfNumbers
}
```

Finally, the last two methods that i think you were trying to create are these:

```
public int amountOfNumbers() {
    return amountOfNumbers; 
}

public int sum() {
  return sum; 
}
```

This is my first post ever so i hope that it helps.

Comment: this works, however the result of average comes to 2 instead of 2.75. I think this is because it is a double. I'm trying to get it to work.

Comment: I am glad i helped.Note that i did not provide you with a complete solution, i just tried to help you understand why your code wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

In `NumberStatistics`, you only need the `count` and a `sum`. You add to the `sum` with `addNumber` (and increment the `count`). Something like,

```
public class NumberStatistics {
    private int count = 0;
    private int sum = 0;

    public void addNumber(int number) {
        this.sum += number;
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int sum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public double average() {
        return sum() / (double) getCount();
    }
}
```